# OWin cookie / wsfederation expires time / sliding expiration ignored

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, security, cookies, owin

I have a Startup.cs class configured like this:

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
 {
      CookieHttpOnly = true,
      SlidingExpiration = true,
      CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always,
      ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
 });

app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
...
```

Inside the application cookie I get (a session lifetime cookie) I can see that the expiry date is always 1 hour ahead of the time it was issued, regardless of what I put in the ExpireTimeSpan property. I've tried bringing the time down to 20 seconds but can happily log into my application 5 minutes later.

Here's a picture of what the Issued / Expires always comes out like:

[image]

Is there something else I need to do to get a combination of using WS-Federation to get a token from an STS, and then backing an application cookie of the returned claims? Am I missing something obvious in how Cookie Authentication works in OWin?

Nuget packages being used for authentication are:

```
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
<package id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.WsFederation" version="3.0.1" targetFramework="net451" />
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Graeme

Comment: @ourmandave nice one - that works a treat. If you want to put that as a response i'll mark it as the answer.